# Updating An object In A Collection C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am not understanding how to update an object referenced in a collection. My collection:

```
List<Person> people
```

I want to update an item in people with an updated object.

```
var existingPepe = people.Where(a => a.id ==someId).FirstOrDefault();
// on examintion existingperson.Age = 101;
Person person = new Person();
person.Age = 65;
```

Now update existingPepe with person;

```
existingPepe = person;
```

But this does not update the Person in the collection - that objects age is till 101  why?

Comment: What's your goal here? `existingPepe.Age = 65;` will update the object that's in the list. Creating a new object and changing the `existingPepe` variable to reference it will not change which object is referenced by the list.

Comment: `existingperson` is a pointer to an object. The `people` collection also has a pointer to that same object. `existingperson = person;` replaced the pointer for `existingperson` to another object **but** the list `people` still contains the reference to the "original" object.

Comment: You have to understand what an object reference is. Here you are pointing a variable to an existing object, then you are replacing that reference with a reference to a new object. The list is still pointing to the original object, you are just pointing the `existingPerson` variable to a new object.

Comment: Ah I see - How should I update the existingPepe?

Comment: `Now update existingPepe with person` No, you are just setting `existingPepe` refer to the same object as the new `person`

Comment: "How should I update the existingPepe" : `existingPepe.Age = 65;` or you could do it in one line: `people.Single(a => a.id ==someId).Age = 65;` assuming there will only ever be exactly 1 match.

Comment: PaulStanley your accepted answer is wrong and its going to have side effect. Please reconsider @Igor answer instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "How should I update the existingPepe"

There is no need to create a new instance of `Person`, you can update the property `Age` on the existing found instance directly. That mutates the actual instance itself. Doing that also means there is no need to swap the item in the `List<Person>`.

```
// note that SingleOrDefault will throw an exception if there is more than one match
var foundPerson = people.SingleOrDefault(a => a.id ==someId);
if(foundPerson != null)
  foundPerson.Age = 65;
// else person with that id does not exist in the list
```

If you want to have an exception thrown if there is no match then use Single instead.

```
var foundPerson = people.Single(a => a.id ==someId);
foundPerson.Age = 65;
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me help you out here. The way to update a `List`, would be to get a reference to the correct spot in the list and update it. Index is one way to do that with a list.

```
var indx = people.FindIndex(a => a.id == someId);
if (indx >= 0) {
    //people[indx].Age = 65; // in case you want to update the found record
    Person person = new Person();
    person.Age = 65;
    people[indx] = person; // set a new Person in the existing slot of the list
}
```

Here I use the `List<T>.FindIndex` function to find the relevant record and then use that index to update the existing record, and then replace that slot with a new person

**Update**

> I want to update an item in people with an **updated object**

To answer the bunch of comments here. I can't assume that the `Person` is a `class` or a `struct`, nor can I tell if it is an `immutable class`. So I cannot assume that the field is update-able. Also, the code in the question, clearly leaves it vague as to, whether the OP wants to update the existing object or set a new object in that slot. Both are very common behavior, and hence my sample demonstrates both, so the OP can decide which one works for them.

Comment: is FindIndex 0 based ?

Comment: Would that fail if it was the first item? Oh i believe it will return -1 if it does not exist.

Comment: This is wrong.  Why are you creating a new person instead of updating the existing

Comment: @Vikhram you are NOT updating an object here.  You are creating a new one.  If you were attempting to delete and replace, your not deleting the old object or copying the old objects values.

Comment: @Vikhram Exactly. In the example, a new Person is instantiated. By instantiating a new Person object, he's basically clearing out any other fields that may be set from the existingPepe. But I'm not sure why index would matter here if it's a List.

Comment: @Vikhram you answers Does NOT Update an object it creates a new one.

Comment: @Vikhram e.g You create a new person with the age of 65.  But the old person has a name of Fred. now the new person does not have a name of Fred.

Comment: @Vikhram, No, 1. This does not show how to update a record. It shows how to replace a record which Will NOT copy over existing values.  2. You're making an assumption in your answer that `people` is a reference directly to the collection, and that if you add back to that List it will add back to the original collection.   So this answer is wrong in 2 ways already.  If you read further into the question   It's quite clear to me that the OP is unclear on reference types, and they're assuming that assigning the reference to `existingPepe = person` will update the existingPepe.

Comment: If you look at @Igors answer, it goes over the OP's misconceptions and answers the question correctly.

Comment: You can't claim that the type might be immutable when *you're mutating it in your code*.  If it was immutable, your code wouldn't work.  This type makes no sense at all as a struct.  If it is one, it's mutable, not representing a single value, unlikely to be/stay small, etc.  It should be changed to be a class if it's not already.  All that said, there are reasons to change the referenced object rather than mutating an existing one.  It all comes down to which behavior is desired, and we can't know that from the code shown.  The question is also ambiguous as to which it's actually asking for.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `existingPepe` contains a reference to the object selected from the list. Setting `existingPepe = person;` changes the reference to point to your new Person object. Variables `existingPepe` and `person` now point to/reference the same object. The original list's reference to the existing person is unaffected by the subsequent operations. You would need to update the list's reference to the existing object to point to your new object by setting it's index.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a person. Then just modify the one you found in memory

```
var existingPepe = people.Where(a => a.id ==someId).FirstOrDefault();
existingPepe.Age = 65;
```

You're old way was creating a new person without adding it to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to update age of a person in that collection you can do it using linq like this

```
people.Where(a => a.id == someId).Select(a => a.Age = 65; return a).ToList();
```

Comment: I would suggest this but isn't the syntax:

people.Where(a => a.id == someId).Select(a => {a.Age = 65; return a;}).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the object itself within the collection, do a remove/add:

```
if(people.Remove(people.Where(a => a.id ==someId).FirstOrDefault()))
people.Add(new Person {Age=65});
```